# I need html Text Input allow only Numeric input plus show me a warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have applied this method, it works perfect.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 &&    event.charCode <= 57'>
    </input>
```

Is it possible when a user try other inputs rather than numeric and it gives a warning message. Help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use jquery validation plugin else you need to write it

Comment: use `<input type="number">`

Comment: You can use `<input type="number" name="number" />` for this!

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFU6VAYUYIAT) code:

```
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>

$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show();
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Example with fadeOut(); 
[Check](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFU6VAYUYIAT)

Comment: you can also use fadeOut to hide the message... like below code
 
//display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;